# Gnuplottex wrong multiplot size

Tags: gnuplottex

I am having an issue with gnuplottex and multiplot. On my windows machine, the size and position at which the pdf is located seem to be calculated wrong. The graph gets squished down in the lowest plot. The labeling and all the text is placed right though. 
I work with miktex.

Here my min working example:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[miktex, subfolder]{gnuplottex}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[h]
    \label{fig:wenaRes}
    \begin{gnuplot}[terminal=cairolatex, terminaloptions = {size 15cm, 15cm}]
        set style line 11 lc rgb '#808080' lt 1
        set border 3 back ls 11
        set tics nomirror
        set xlabel "x"
        set ylabel "y"

        set multiplot layout 2, 1 title 'Multiplot title'           
        plot [-4:4] sin(x) with lines
        plot [-4:4] cos(x) with lines


    \end{gnuplot}   
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This gives me the following page:
[image: Figure of squished multiplot graph]

If needed I can add the generated tex file by gnuplottex.

Comment: Does this work if you run it in gnuplot directly?

Comment: @Simon T., for me, running your code with `pdfLatex` gives the right output with `MikTex 2.9` as well as  `TeXLive 2019`. Maybe something wrong in the compile/run configurations of your `LaTeX` editor?

Comment: Running it with gnuplot directly gives me the same output. I tried the epslatex terminal too. Same issue. 
Hasty, I tried to use the tikz terminal but had some tikz related issues. 

@Nako, I use MikTex 2.9 too and one week prior to this post I updated everything via the MiKTeX Console. I use gnuplot 5.3 patchlevel 0.

Edit: Sorry for the late response.

Comment: I ran pdflatex as follows: `pdflatex --enable-write18 test.tex`
Same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments I used gnuplot 5.3. I switched to a slightly older version (5.2.7) and now it works fine.